# Azure ARM and SQL Database size

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Here is the portion of my ARM file about the database:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "name": "[concat(variables('SqlServerName'), '/', variables('dbName'))]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Database"
      },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('SqlServerName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "collation": "[parameters('dbCollation')]",
        "edition": "[parameters('dbEdition')]",
        "maxSizeBytes": "53687091200",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('dbRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
      }
}
```

And here my parameters:

```
    "dbEdition": {
      "value": "Standard"
    },
    "dbRequestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "value": "S2"
    }
```

But these database properties are ignored and the deployed database doesn't respect them.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

As @SwathiDhanwada pointed out in comments, the `edition` property may not exist as per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template).
I should use `sku` defined like:

[image]

Yet the powershell script to get a list of available skus for a given location returns something like:

[image]

The headers of the table are not the same as the properties of the sku object ‍♂️

Comment: The property edition doesn't exist within ARM template. You need to use tier property within to specify the edition. For more information, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

Comment: Tks. Yet the doc mentions sku and its properties but the powershell script to get a list of available skus for a given location returns a table with column headers which are the not the sku properties...

Comment: I assume the properties are aligned as : skuname-sku ; tier-edition ;family -Family